# APIs are not migrated when updating wso2 am 1.9.0 to 1.10.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I followed the instructions to the word when upgrading wso2 api maanager from 1.9.0 to 1.10.0:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Upgrading+from+the+Previous+Release

However, the APIs from 1.9.0 were not showing up in the upgraded 1.10.0. Some details might be missing from the instructions. Anyone had similar experience?

P.S.: I even tried API import/export tool(one API a time), but importing 1.9.0 exported API zip package to 1.10.0 also failed with NoMethodFoundException(getContext()).

Comment: Can you provide more information about migration? Which database you are using, do you have any errors?

Comment: The database is mariaDB.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to give up, and this question can be closed. I end up installing wso2 am 1.10.0 brand new, and manually add apis from version 1.9.0. WSO2 team needs to listen to the community: this is not acceptable, considering the two versions are so close (from am 1.9.0 to 1.10.0, only version skipped is 1.9.1)

Comment: @JD If you need others to help you, you need to provide sufficient information. You have not responded to Abimaran's 2nd question. Without that information I'm afraid no one can help you.

Comment: Sorry I tried several times. The upgrade is fine, but the APIs from 1.9.0 were not ported to 1.10.0 following the instructions. As mentioned above, I gave up and don't recall all the details while I worked on it. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Really sorry about the incontinence caused. I would like to add one small thing to this thread as you are creating same API in another version from the scratch. When you implement API you can extract swagger definition for that API. Then when you create same API in another deployment you can paste same swagger definition and create same API(it will create all resource mapping etc). However you may need to add some other details if necessary. But you can copy most of the API details.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. I actually did this way after several manual additions (basically exported swgger json file and then imported into new system)